# Login failed for "user" in ssis

Tags: ssis

```
[Load_Row table [9928]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  
The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "DB_NAME" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  
There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.

[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: component "Load_Row table" (9928) failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.

[Connection manager "Raven_MSSQL"] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E4D.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E4D  Description: "Login failed for user '****'."
```

I am getting above error for 10-12 packages in my pre-prod environment .

But Couple of week before, It was fine and loaded the data.

I have checked the config files and could see no changes happened and everything looks same.But when I downloaded the same package from server and executed, i got the same error.After google, I changed the protection level and executed, it got succeeded.

> Do I want to change the protection level and re-deploy ?

Please put your suggestion which helps me to overcome this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You must be using proxy account to run jobs. Those proxy accounts have credentials. Check if password for those credentials are updated or not.

Comment: I checked with DB team,they said no changes were happened in proxy ..they said no changes were happened ..I changed owner as "sa" ,package got succeed ..can I know how it happened @ Prabhat

Comment: "sa" is the master user. Hence it can execute. I'm confident that your system user's password must have expired. That's why login is failing. As a best practice, we shouldn't use 'sa' everywhere.

Comment: Thanks Prabhat :) .. Packages are getting success if I moved to "SA"..
By keeping this credentials, I can check with DB team for proxy and owner.